# Flux-density increase due to winding inductance

Tags: power-electronics

I am currently designing the power transformer or HF-transformer for
the use in a DAB topology and need help in regard of controlling the flux-density swing.

I have already selected the ferrite-core combination required for my use
and calculated the necessary parameters such as the heat-limited
flux-density swing or the permissible current density. In the current
configuration a maximum power transfer of 16kW (less is required) should be possible at 200kHz.
The formula I use to calculate the transferable power is based on the context that the
primary winding occupies approximately (minus the fill factor) half of the total winding space.
In my case, this would mean a required primary turn count of around 6 to transfer the maximum power of 16kW.

Now to the question itself: I check the flux density swing with the formula:
ΔB=(L∗I²)/(Amin∗N)
and come to the conclusion that the inductance of the winding with N1 = 6 generates a flux-density swing that is well above the heat-limited flux-density swing. The consequence I draw from this is that an air gap (about 1mm) is required to bring the AL-Value of the core down and thus reduce the inductance so far that the required flux-density increase is adhered to again.

Am I wrong in assuming that the winding inductance is affecting the flux-density swing? In various documents regarding this topic core-combinations are selected and the number of windings applied there would, to my mind, mean and instantaneous saturation of the ferrite core with the given parameters. I have various sources which state that power-transformers usually dont use air-gaps but fail to explain why exactly that is the case. Am I wrong in my assumptions and what are the associated draw-backs in using an air-gap in this configuration?

Comment: If one calculation gives you 16 kW for transferable power, and another calculation shows that exceeding the saturation flux density, then at least one of your calculations is wrong. Perhaps present both formulae and workings into your question so that we can see where you've gone wrong. Basically forward transformers want the highest inductance possible so no airgap, flybacks need an airgap to reduce inductance to the correct operating level. They are totally different operation philosophies, you can't fix a forward design by adding a flyback's airgap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a gap, the effective permeability of the core reduces and, for your 6 turns there is proportionately less inductance. If inductance has reduced, then it's very, very highly likely that what ever voltage you apply to the primary will produce a current that is significantly more than what you are currently considering. Look at the formula you used: -

$$ΔB=\dfrac{L\times I^2}{A_{MIN} \times N}$$

Clearly, reducing inductance may appear to make ΔB smaller but it is more than countered by the current increasing and, for ΔB that's a squared factor. Hence adding a gap is not going to work without increasing the number of turns to restore the inductance. That is the only way to reduce the effect of saturation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The current I used for this calculation is limited by the dab-topology. If the current flowing into the transformer is being controlled from the outside then surely an inductance decrease wouldnt change that?

Comment: If current is set externally and not defined by inductance then adding a gap is a good idea @L.T.

Comment: I will also add that a DAB converter doesn't usually have restrictions on current of this sort other than by correct use of duty cycles. What I'm saying is be very careful about what your assumptions are. I cannot add anything else given that I have no idea what your circuit might be.

Comment: I understand, thank you. What I was trying to confirm was whether the value of the inductance affects the flux-density swing considering a given current. If the current is actually fixed at the value I considered it to be, would the use of an airgap be feasible or are there other major drawbacks associated with doing so given the dab-topology?

Comment: Ampere turns are directly related to to the generation of peak flux density. This plus the length of the core that the magnetic field travels around produce magnetic field strength, H i.e. \$At/\ell\$ is H and, H times effective permeability is flux density.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me or is your formula wrong?

I think the current in the formula is in power of 1 not power of 2.

[image: magnetic equvilent circuit]

The flux \$\Phi\$ is equal to the flux density \$B\$ times the cross sectional area \$A\$. The reluctance is \$Rel\$:

\$N \cdot I = (B \cdot A) \cdot Rel\$

\$B = \Large {{N \cdot I} \over {A \cdot Rel}}\$

We know from magnetic theory that the reluctance of a magnetic circuit is \$\large N^2 \over L\$, so:

\$B = \Large {{N \cdot I} \over {{(A \cdot N^2)} / L}} = {{L \cdot I} \over {A \cdot N}}\$